# how to change cancel/done button color in ion-picker

Tags: sass, colors, ionic4

i want to change the done/button color, cancel should be red and done should be green

[image]

I already tried this:

```css
ion-picker{
  .picker-toolbar-cancel{
    color: red !important;
  }
}

.ui-datepicker {
  color: red;
}

ion-picker > div > div > div > button {
  color: red;
}
```

here is my html:

```html
        <ion-datetime
          displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
          pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY">
        </ion-datetime>
       <span class="caption2">até</span>
        <ion-datetime
          displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
          pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY">
        </ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is happening because the date picket is set in the root of the app instead of inside the component.

One of the solution is to use your selectors but in your `global.scss`, but that will apply to all ion-datetime across the app.

Another option is to set a class to the buttons and also modify it inside of your `global.scss` e.g:

**global.scss:**

```
.picker-button.sc-ion-picker-md.test{
  background: forestgreen;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-datetime [pickerOptions]="customPickerOptions" 
              displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
              pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY">
  </ion-datetime>
```

**TS:**

```
customPickerOptions: any;
constructor() {
    this.customPickerOptions = {
      buttons: [{
        color: 'red',
        text: 'Save',
        cssClass: 'test',
        handler: () => console.log('Clicked Save!')
      }, {
        text: 'Log',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Clicked Log. Do not Dismiss.');
          return false;
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

That would prevent to do it across the whole app

Comment: works! i just put ``.picker-button{
  color: green;
}`` in global.scss!

Comment: Have in mind that it would be applied to all your ion-datepicket. Nice to hear it